# How to prove $b=c$ if $ab=ac$ (cancellation law in groups)?

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove for a group $G$, that if 
$$a\circ b =a\circ c$$ then this is true $$b=c$$
I started with $b=b\circ e$, but this didn't help me at all.

Next I tried with this:
$$(a\circ b)\circ c=a\circ (b\circ c)$$ but I don't know/understand how to go further. How can I prove this equation?

Comment: See also: [Cancellation property in groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673485/cancellation-property-in-groups) and [Proof of the right and left cancellation laws for Groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301324/proof-of-the-right-and-left-cancellation-laws-for-groups)

Comment: Divide both sides by a.

Comment: I think you have to make sure $a$ is not $0$.

Comment: When I was teaching, I wouldn't let my students use the word "cancel".  If they did, I would have them identify if they were using the additive inverse or the multiplicative inverse (I wanted them to actually think about what they were doing and why).  If this case, you're using the Distributive Property.

Comment: @theonlygusti Groups don't have division.  You can left multiply by the inverse, but that's circular reasoning: the point of this is to prove that left multiplying by the inverse doesn't change the equation.

Comment: @Teepeemm, no, that is not the point.

Comment: @kleineg, what is this $0$ that you talk about?

Comment: the group operation is multiplication (juxtaposition) or addition?

Comment: @CharlieHorse: Then you better teach yourself what is a **group**. In a group there is **no such thing** as "distributive property".

Comment: @marshalcraft: Neither. In this question the group operation is $\circ$.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Suppose $$a\cdot b = a\cdot c$$ Let $a^{-1}$ be the inverse element of $a$ in $G$ (s.t. $a^{-1}\cdot a = a\cdot a^{-1} = e$ where $e$ is the identity element), which must exist by the axioms of groups. Now consider

$$a^{-1}\cdot(a \cdot b) =a^{-1}\cdot(a\cdot c)$$

By associativity, we have

$$(a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot b = (a^{-1}\cdot a)\cdot c$$

By the definition of inverse, we have

$$e\cdot b = e\cdot c$$

where $e$ is the identity element (s.t. $e\cdot x = x\cdot e = x$ for all $x \in G$). By the definition of the identity element,

$$b = c$$

Comment: This is why, as a physicist, I never understood math proofs.  Since $a\neq0$, why not just say *a cancels on both sides* or whathaveyou?

Comment: Because that's what you have to prove.

Comment: @user1717828 For two reasons. One, you're in a group, not a ring. A Rubik's cube (or rather sequences of moves on it) is an example of a group. There's no "zero." There's an identity -- doing nothing -- but more often we denote that "1" and whether you can cancel "a" has nothing to do with whether "a = 1." The other is that we're trying to prove the think you're asking "why can't we just say this." It's *false* in many important *rings*. So you need to understand when it's true and prove it.

Comment: Here's a counter-example of why you can't just "cancel on both sides":  Let $A$ be a matrix.  If $A \vec{v} = A \vec{w}$, does it follow that $\vec{v} = \vec{w}$?  Answer: not unless $A$ has an inverse, and not all matrices have inverses.

Comment: @user1717828 There is actually substance to this proof - i.e. it says that if we have inverses then we have cancellation. There are common systems without cancellation - like modular arithmetic - so we definitely shouldn't treat it as an axiom. If we start with $$3\cdot 3 \equiv 3\cdot 1 \pmod{6}$$
Then we just cancel on both sides, then we get
$$3\equiv 1\pmod{6}.$$
Whoops.

Comment: Nice; for complete clarity I might start with the reflexive statement $a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot b) = a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot b)$?

Comment: @user1717828 I don't think this has anything to do with being a physicist - I've always thought it was a symptom of bad (or insufficiently deep) math education. It's very common among students of all quantitative fields that they memorize the rule of cancellation without understanding _why_ things can be cancelled, and that gets them into trouble when dealing with more sophisticated situations like matrices, modular arithmetic, differential operators, etc.

Comment: Should note that $a^{-1}$ is equal to $1/a$, which explains why there's no proof of equality when $a = 0$.  You can't multiply a number by something undefined and get a defined result, so that covers every situation.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: but the question concerns a general group with operator $\circ$. We don't usually introduce the $/$ notation for anything other than multiplication, and it'd be wrong to say $a^{-1}$ is equal to $1/a$ in the case where $\circ$ is addition.

Comment: Let's hope that the existence of left inverses is among the axioms ;)

Comment: @CarstenS: well, technically it doesn't actually *need* to be among the axioms. You can state the group axioms with only right inverses and a right identity, and prove from that the existence of left inverses and a left identity, and that the lefts are equal to the rights. You do this using everyone's favourite elementary group lemma, $z\circ z = z \Rightarrow z = e$, applied to $a^{-1}a$ (where $a^{-1}$ is the right inverse) to prove it's also a left inverse, and then $e\circ a = a \circ a^{-1} \circ a = a \circ e = a$ shows $e$ is a left identity.

Comment: @user1717828 In physics, why do we need water and a solid object to show Archimedes' Principle? Why can't we just see that it's true because we know the object displaces an amount of water equivalent to its own mass?

Comment: @SteveJessop: A 'shorter' way is $a'∘a = a'∘a∘e = a'∘a∘a'∘a'' = a'∘e∘a'' = a'∘a'' = e$ and then $e∘a = a∘a'∘a = a∘e = a$ (where $a'$ is the right-inverse of $a$ and $e$ is the right-identity).

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**:

If you know that $4\cdot x = 4\cdot y$, how do you prove that $x=y$?

**Hint 2:**

Think about *inverses*

Comment: Because N is closed under multiplication.

Comment: I'm sorry when I said multiplication I meant multiplication, not the operation you just made up.

Comment: Because Z is an ACRU with a nonempty subset N with trichotomy that is closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Associative commutative ring with unit. *My* point was that you first hint rather begs the question.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, we know $a,b,c \in G$
$$b = e∘b = (a^{-1}∘a)∘b = a^{-1}∘(a∘b)=a^{-1}∘(a∘c) = (a^{-1}∘a)∘c = c$$

Comment: Where is $e$ is neutral element in $G$

Comment: And where you use $'$ to denote the inverse (this is probably a bad idea in general).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft why? We know that in $G$ $\exists a, a': a∘a' = a'∘a = e$

Comment: It is a bad idea because the inverse is denoted by $a^{-1}$. This is universal when working with groups written multiplicatively. Using ' is something done temporarily until it has been established that the inverse is unique and two-sided. This also frees up ' to denote alternative elements.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ok, I understand you

Answer (score 6):

$G$ is a group. One of the axioms of a group is that every element has an inverse. This means that $a\in G$ has an inverse $a^{-1} \in G$. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

By the group properties each element has an inverse. So you can just multiply your equation on the left by $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply both sides of the given equation
$$
a\circ b=a\circ c
$$
on the left by the inverse of $a$ to get the desired result.