# Why is the 'Law of Cancellation' for groups only an implication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is easy to see that for a Group $G$ and $a,b \in G$

> $ab = ac \Rightarrow  b = c$

(See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666880/how-to-prove-b-c-if-ab-ac-cancellation-law-in-groups))

But what is about the other direction? That is:

> $b = c \Rightarrow ab = ac$

Does this implication hold as well?

Answer (score 4):

Of course the other direction holds. The other direction has nothing to do with groups or with anything really; it's just what *equality* means! Saying $a=b$ means that $a$ and $b$ are exactly the same thing; if $a$ and $b$ are the same thing then $ac$ and $bc$ are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. In a group, you are allowed to left-multiply the expression $b = c$ with the group element $a$ to get $ab = ac$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the other way holds. This is essentially just the fact that multiplication is well-defined. The reason that they do not list the cancellation law as an if and only if is that the other way doesn't actually have to do with cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

The group multiplication  is a binary operation on the set of elements of the group, associating to each pair $\langle u,v\rangle$ of elements of $G$ a new element $uv$. When you have $b=c$, you are fixing, let's say, the right argument of this binary operation, and what you are left with is an ordinary function of one argument: the left-multiplication by elements of $G$. As you certainly know, a function associates to each element of its domain ($G$ in this case) one and only one element of its image (again $G$).